# Switching to an event wrapped in monadic context

Tags: frp, reflex

My specific problem is like this:

Given an `Event t [a]` and an `Event t ()` (let's say it's a tick event), I want to produce an `Event t a`, that is, an event that is giving me consecutive items from input list for every occurence of tick event.

Reflex has following helper:

```
zipListWithEvent :: (Reflex t, MonadHold t m, MonadFix m) => (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> Event t b -> m (Event t c)
```

which is doing exactly what I want, but does not take an event as an input, but just a list. Given that I have an `Event t [a]`, I thought I could produce an event containing event and just switch, but the problem is that `zipListWithEven` operates in monadic context, therefore I can get:

```
Event t (m (Event t a))
```

which is something that `switch` primitive does not accept.

Now, maybe I'm approaching it in wrong way, so here's my general problem. Given an event that's producing list of coordinates and tick event, I want to produce an event that I can "use" to move an object along the coordinates. So each time tick fires, the position is updated. And each time I update the coordinates list, it begins to produce positions from that new list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if I understand the semantics of your desired functions correctly, but in the reactive-banana library, I would solve the problem like this:

```
trickle :: MonadMoment m => Event [a] -> Event () -> Event a
trickle eadd etick = do
    bitems <- accumB [] $ unions    -- 1
        [ flip (++) <$> eadd        -- 2
        , drop 1    <$  etick       -- 3
        ]
    return $ head <$> filterE (not . null) (bitems <@ etick) -- 4
```

The code works as follows:

1. The Behavior `bitems` records the current lists of items.
2. Items are added when `eadd` happens, ...
3. ... and one item is removed when `etick` happens.
4. The result is an event that happens whenever `etick` happens, and that contains the first element of the (previously) current list whenever that list is nonempty.

This solution does not seem to require any fancy or intricate reasoning.

Comment: It's not exactly what I wanted (it accumulates yhe incoming lists, whereas I wanted to replace the source of coordinates every time new arrives), but I think it is not significant difference and it shows the approach. I now think I know what were my problem in thinking, and I will try to translate it to reflex as soon as I'm in front of computer, thanks!

Comment: Yep, worked with minor adjustements! It's great the FRP semantics are common so someone not using one particular lib can be of help:)

Answer (score 1):

Naming the parts:

```
coords :: Event t [Coord]
ticks  :: Event t ()
```

If we want to remember the most recent `Coord` until the next firing of `ticks`, then we necessarily have to be in the some monad `Reflex m`. This is the monad that allow the transient `Event` to be persisted.

The core thing you'd like to remember is a stack of `Coord`. Let's try this:

```
data Stack a = CS {
    cs_lastPop :: Maybe a
  , cs_stack   :: [a]
  } deriving (Show)

stack0 = CS Nothing []

pop :: Stack a -> Stack a
pop (CS _ []    ) = CS Nothing []
pop (CS _ (x:xs)) = CS (Just x) xs

reset :: [a] -> Stack a -> Stack a
reset cs (CS l _) = CS l cs
```

Nothing reactive there yet, two functions that tweak the `Stack Coord` in the way you mention in your question.

The reflex code to drive this would build a `Dynamic t (Stack Coord)`, by specifying its initial state and all the things that modify it:

```
  coordStack <- foldDyn ($) stack0 (leftmost [
      reset <$> coords
    , pop   <$  ticks
    ])
```

The `leftmost` here takes a list of `Stack Coord -> Stack Coord` functions, which are applied in turn to `stack0` by `foldDyn ($)` *(as long as `coords` and `ticks` never occur in same frame)*.

Driving all this in `main`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = mainWidget $ do
  t0 <- liftIO getCurrentTime

  -- Some make up 'coords' data, pretending (Coord ~ Char)
  coordTimes <- tickLossy 2.5 t0
  coords <- zipListWithEvent (\c _ -> c) ["greg","TOAST"] coordTimes

  ticks <- tickLossy 1 t0

  coordStack <- foldDyn ($) stack0 (leftmost [
      reset <$> coords
    , pop   <$  ticks
    ])

  display coordStack
```

Comment: I like how it goes from just normal datatype/functions and then make it reactive in just one expression. Good to have that in mind, considering FRP seems so much of a paradigm shift that it's easy to get lost in its intricacies instead of keeping calm and just writing functional code ;)